# Cookies Not Being Set in Production in Next.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cookies, next.js13

I'm working on a Next.js application where I'm setting a cookie after a successful login. The cookie is supposed to store an authentication token. This works as expected in my local development environment, but when deployed to production, the cookie is not being set.

Here's the function I use to set the cookie:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

async function saveCookie(token) {
    Cookies.set('auth_token', token, {
        httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        expires: 60,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        sameSite: 'lax',
        path: '/',
    });
}
```

In production, the login functionality works, and the API returns a token as expected. However, the `auth_token` cookie does not appear in the browser's cookie storage.

Attached is a screenshot showing that the user is logged in (indicating the token is received), but the cookie is not visible in the browser's cookies.

[image]

I have deployed the frontend on Netlify with an environment variable `NODE_ENV=production`.

Why is the cookie not being set in the production environment, despite other parts of the application running as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may need to set the expires time for one day

> 1 Day = 24 Hrs = 24*60*60 = 86400.

and same site set the none and also set domain name then it works

> Cookies.set('auth_token', token, {
> domain: 'here name',
> expires: 1/86400,
> secure: true,
> sameSite: 'None',
> path: '/',
> });

I hope this solution resolves your issue.

Comment: so there is no need for the `httpOnly`? i thought that value helped against hacking attacks?